# How to read "Set-Cookie" generated from asp.net core API?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Domain 1 sends a http request to an API in domain 2.

The HttpResponseMessage headers contain "Set-Cookie" which is as below.
How can I read this cookie from the response and attach to another response which will do a redirect to domain 2 ?
Thank you!

.AspNetCore.Cookies=CfDJ8O9xThwMNOhChcuBECE1VXHz3M0rFuwIeZqKbZckvkDXflMWbJYxtVS12ImQCV7dbdHP9rRMp2JblrWTJMdRHvuOQ_kyYXQrU5DF98e4NEOLfrCOwYv0ReLCljm75A0IEIQOu2Moa4TV6SgE21T7RTFsvlY0YcGO6KjYZbfcHbZh5wCQNvFzMvWSkZ_woEgxdC9822gXAgOqMw5EoFkJPV4UujuiGuwqSHouwgG1DhVIHsvW47ICe6x4cT13suZKygNdIHkSqIS3h01Z5nyT5aucTcd-mwurFtrMJ-0SVnBkm5D32ZWbgijMDDcJVCKtdzxPJBuUYrcGi2thhKAgrC_PBB7G5XgH0QuFle_ZKhus74FO5QCYW81wb_-87aCZDGiijBgPtmID3yim_BGJnCVYbRdz9kyNEfE5RzW-6dl13wZGd7c9B25om_08xZmZnnQB8a--t742sybuMpmchvQExvM3w9dVkmq_tb9Bhrk0J_hbMH8HJ52GbKiFkpuKl1oxz8VHak-caXYjWo9z8kd5rJMdJOQhMJgn_SJ2tLkp6LtBnrCNGjhvIFtS3YHIiw; expires=Tue, 11 Jun 2019 12:09:42 GMT; path=/; samesite=lax; httponly

Domain 1

```
public async void Start(string req, int id)
{
    HttpResponseMessage res = await PostHTTPResponse(string.Format("/API/Update?req={0}", req));

    IEnumerable<string> values;
    if (res.Headers.TryGetValues("Set-Cookie", out values))
    {
        // How to read the Set-Cookie here and attach it to the response object below?
    }

    var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

    //Redirect to domain 2 with cookie attached to response.
    response.Redirect(string.Format("http://localhost:58379/Update?id={0}", id));
}
```

Domian 2 is asp.net core.
Below is how I generated the cookie in domian 2 API.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Update")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Update(string req)
{
    List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>();

    claims.Add(new Claim(Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.UserName,
                                 req));

    var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(
      claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        IsPersistent = true
    };

    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
        authProperties);

    return this.Json(data: new { IsAuthenticated = this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated });
}
```

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. The real issue seems to be that you're wanting to share authentication, and this is not the way to do that. Particularly with APIs, cookie auth shouldn't be being used at all. Instead, you should be authenticating via a bearer token or such.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to share bearer token between APIs? Thanks!